# Is "to be" in "to be or not to be" used as a linking verb with no nominal nor adjectival predicate?

Tags: copular-verbs

Is "to be" in "to be or not to be" used as a linking verb with no nominal nor adjectival predicate?

Is it grammatically correct, and if so what rules govern that omission?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not used as a linking verb. It's used as a synonym for "exist" or "live". "To live, or not to live, that is the question." Hamlet is contemplating suicide.

Comment: that makes sense, sorry i wasn't aware that would exclude it from being a linking verb!